# Java split string to Double[ ]

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-8

I have this string:

`((39.4189453125 37.418708616699824,42.0556640625 37.418708616699824,43.4619140625 34.79181436843146,38.84765625 33.84817790215085,39.4189453125 37.418708616699824))`

I want to convert it to `Double []` java array.

I have tried:

```
String[]tokens = myString.split(" |,");
Arrays.asList(tokens).stream().map(item -> Double.parseDouble(item)).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray();
```

Is there any nicer and more efficient way instead of the array-list-array conversion ?

Comment: You don't need to collect them to a list. You can go straight from a stream to an array using [`toArray(Double[]::new)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-)

Comment: Also, if you need `Double`s rather than `double`s, you might use [`Double.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) instead of [`Double.parseDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Avoid `Double` which wastes a *lot* of memory and is much slower.

Comment: @khelwood can i make it double[] ?

Comment: @EladBenda2 Yes, if you use `mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)` you will get a `DoubleStream`.

Comment: Your input looks more like an array of pairs of doubles (such as the GPS coordinates of lat/long points of a polygon). Are you sure you don't want a double [][2] (a two-dimensional array)?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou yes, i'm calling a double[] signature, but would love to see how you would make the split return `double [][2]` ?

Comment: @EladBenda2 see answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-|\\.");

pattern.splitAsStream(test) // your String
       .map(Double::parseDouble)
       .toArray(Double[]::new);
```

Also your pattern looks weird, seems like this would fit better `[-,\\s]+`

Comment: @BoristheSpider I *love* more the `Scanner.findAll` in java-9

Comment: Wouldn't `Double::valueOf` be preferable to `Double.parseDouble` (which returns a `double` that needs to be autoboxed)?

Comment: @khelwood meh - boxed here or boxed there; don't make much difference.

Comment: I'm still not convinced this answer would work, based on the given pattern and the OP's sample input.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou yeah, pattern is most odd.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou right - it fails indeed, but I was just "transforming" whatever the OP had in place, will update

Comment: @Eugene how can i convert it to `double[]` instead of `Double[]` ?

Comment: @EladBenda2 `pattern.splitAsStream(test).mapToDouble(Double::valueOf).toArray();`

Comment: @Eugene If you use `mapToDouble(Double::valueOf)`, that is _definitely_ unnecessary boxing and unboxing.

Comment: @khelwood wrong copy/paste here, it should have been `Double::parseDouble`, good catch

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can do it using `doubles` instead of `Doubles`.

```
String string = "1 2 3 4";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" |,");

double[] results = pattern.splitAsStream(string)
                          .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                          .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input data appears to be a series of pairs of numbers, so here's how to get a `double[][2]` array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String data = "(("
            + "39.4189453125 37.418708616699824,"
            + "42.0556640625 37.418708616699824,"
            + "43.4619140625 34.79181436843146,"
            + "38.84765625   33.84817790215085,"
            + "39.4189453125 37.418708616699824"
            + "))";

    final Pattern topLevelPattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\((.*)\\)\\)");
    final Pattern pairSeparator = Pattern.compile(",");

    Matcher topLevelMatcher = topLevelPattern.matcher(data);
    if (!topLevelMatcher.matches())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data not surrounded by double parentheses");

    String topLevelData = topLevelMatcher.group(1);  // whatever's inside the parentheses

    double[][] pairsArray = pairSeparator.splitAsStream(topLevelData)
            .map(s -> s.split("\\s+"))  // array[2] of strings representing doubles
            .map(a -> new double[]{Double.parseDouble(a[0]), Double.parseDouble(a[1])})
            .toArray(double[][]::new);

    for (double[] pair : pairsArray)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pair));
}
```